# Can the elements of vector belong to different classes in R?

Tags: r, vector

I have just started R programming language and this is something I wanted to clear it up. can someone explain this.
or
Is it that the elements must belong to the same class?

I have read articles about this, but is still confusing so turning to the community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it for yourself:

```
v = c(1,2,'3')
```

This might make you think R accepts multiple classes, but if you print it, you get the following:

```
[1] "1" "2" "3"
```

They're all strings. So, no, you might type a vector with multiple classes, but R will try to turn it into a common class.